# Which career perspectives are open for a graduate student with a Ph.D. in Environmental Studies?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I am a prospective Ph.D. student in Environmental Studies. I came across your profile and I could see you completed a PhD program in Environmental Studies. I need an advice regarding the matter of making a decision to dedicate my next 5-6 years to a Ph.D. program in Environmental Studies, I would appreciate assistance in such a vital decision for me.

I am an International student getting my bachelor's degree in International Relations and Environmental Studies in May 2024. My next step is to skip my MA program (lack of financial support) and pursue my Ph.D. in Environmental Studies. My field of study will be human-environment relations, environmental justice towards disadvantaged communities, equality of distribution of green technologies, and the role of social factors in this matter.

To avoid making a wrong step in meeting my academic and career expectations, I wanted to ask Ph.D. students which career perspectives have opened for them once they get their Ph.D. in Environmental studies.

With this type of degree, there is mostly a chance to become a Professor? Is it a narrow sector of jobs available for you?

I dream about working in the UN environmental assembly and international environmental organizations.

Could you tell me which careers are opened specifically for those who are applying for a Ph.D. in Environmental Studies?

Thank you. I would really appreciate your assistance in this important decision for me.

Respectfully,

Undergraduate student Iuliia